# jquery - add event handler on event that takes another event as argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function scheduleAdd when the enter button is hit, but I only want it to work if an input with the id 'addSchedule' is in focus. Here's what I have:

```
    $('#addSchedule').focus(function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;  
    if(evt.keyCode == 13) {scheduleAdd};
 });
```

I know the code inside the .focus works, because I tried it on its own and it triggers the function scheduleAdd when the enter key is hit. How can I make this conditional on 'addSchedule' being in focus?

Also, more generally, I was wondering if there's a standard way to ascribe event handlers conditional on a second event, such as nesting .on() or something.

Thanks.

Comment: In the `scheduleAdd()` function check if the specified `<input>` has focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/8523y33h/1/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input id="addSchedule" type="text" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#addSchedule').keydown(function (event) {
     if (event.which == 13) {
         event.preventDefault();    // This will prevent the page refresh.
         scheduleAdd();
     }
     function scheduleAdd() {
         alert("Add the schedule");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply the `keydown` event, and decide to do something or nothing based on whether the current element has the specified id:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function() {
    if (!$("#addSchedule").is(":focus")) return;
    // do stuff
});
```

Alternatively you can also check for the identity of the focused element with `document.activeElement.id === "addSchedule"` if you don't mind that's not enough jQuery. ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I was think it would be more efficient to trigger the if loop every time 'addSchedule' was in focus rather than every time the enter key is hit, but I guess it will hardly make a difference.

Comment: @user3220303: You can add the event handler on focus of `#addSchedule` and remove it on blur, or you can have the handler inspect a flag that you set on focus and unset on blur. But yes, that will have zero practical benefit. You can't produce keydown events fast enough for it to matter.